# Automatic Emails after adding new clients/prospects

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Ok, We have been trying to find a way to send an automatic email to new clients/prospects that we add into our CRM. Is it possible? If there's no easy way, what's the complicated way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

How about a workflow?

- [Creating Workflows - Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Series by Zero2Ten](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B5efFw5Vpk)
- [Tutorial: Creating a sales process with stages using a workflow](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/RC/2011/en-us/online/5.1_CTP/salesworkflow.aspx)